# sqlplus: command not found Using SSH on Windows to VMware linux

Tags: oracle, linux, oracle-12c, vmware, ssh

I have oracle Database 12c in a virtual machine with the database working normally in a linux environment (Centos).

Through windows, using ssh I was able to connect to the linux virtual machine. But when I try to connect the database using 'sqlplus' command, I get the following error.
bash: sqlplus: command not found...
[image: output after run comand 'sqlplus']

Comment: What's your question, exactly? Did you check if the Oracle environment variables are sourced in the `oracle` user profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqlplus executable will be installed in the bin/ subdirectory under the Oracle Home directory for the database you're working with.  Setting up the Environment Variables on the database server is usually done using the **oraenv** shell script.
The trick, of course, is that this, *too*, is installed in the bin/ subdirectory of an Oracle Home directory!

Your .bashrc or .bash_profile should, at the very least, set the ORACLE_SID and PATH Environment Variables and, if you want, make a call to **oraenv** to set up the rest.

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1

export PATH=${PATH}:${ORACLE_HOME}/bin

# Use db1
ORAENV_ASK=NO
export ORACLE_SID=db1
. oraenv
ORAENV_ASK=YES
```

See [Database Administrator's Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UNXAR/admin_ora.htm#UNXAR120)